# NodeJS API not found

Tags: node.js, express

I tested my NodeJS API endpoint from Linux VPS server direct from the browser by giving a simple testing endpoint and real endpoint that I use in production. The simple testing endpoint that is router.get() worked but the router.post() cannot be found i.e the response the browser returned. For technical assistance, please find my code below:

### greetme.js

--> This is in controller directory

```
exports.getGreetMe = async (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Congratulations Developer!!! You can access the api server.");
};
```

I have signin and onboarding functions in auth_onboardingController.js and this file is in controller directory too

### auth_onboardingController.js

```
const onboarding = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const userid = common_helper.userid();
        const emailActivation = common_helper.emailActivation(userid.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ""));
        const phoneActivationCode = common_helper.getRandomNumberBetween(100000, 900000);
        const loggedIP = req.header('x-forwarded-for'); // || req.message.connection.remoteAddress;

        const schema = joi.object({
            fullname: joi.string().max(75).required().label("Full Name / Business Name is required"),
            email: joi.string().email().max(65).required().label("Email is required and must be reasonable"),
            phone: joi.string().required().label("Phone number is required and must be 11 digits"),
            password: joi.string().max(125).required().label("Password is required"),
            registeras: joi.string().max(10).required().label("Please choose how you want to be registered"),
            userid: joi.string().required().label("User ID is required"),
            emailActivation: joi.string().required().label("Email Activation is required"),
            phoneActivationCode: joi.string().required().label("Phone Activation Code is required"),
            loggedIP: joi.string().required().label("Logged IP is required")
        });

        const {
            error
        } = schema.validate(req.body);

        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        }

        const fullname = req.body.fullname;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const phone = req.body.phone;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const registeras = req.body.registeras;

        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRound, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }


            let sqlQuery = 'call OnboardingSP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
            connection.query(sqlQuery, [req.body.userid, req.body.fullname, req.body.phone, req.body.email, hash, req.body.registeras, req.body.emailActivation, req.body.phoneActivationCode, req.body.loggedIP], (err, result) => {

                console.log(req.body.userid, req.body.fullname, req.body.phone, req.body.email, hash, req.body.registeras, req.body.emailActivation, req.body.phoneActivationCode, req.body.loggedIP);
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        onboarded: false,
                        message: "Your registration cannot be completed at the moment",
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log(result);

                    let subject = "Test Company: Verify your email address";

                    //send email activation code here
                    emailactivation.sendConfirmationEmail(fullname, subject, emailActivation);

                    return res.status(200).json({
                        onboarded: true,
                        message: "success",
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error in create`, e);
        next(e);
    }
}
```

### auth_onboardingController.js signin() function

same as above but for signin operation

### index.js

This is in routes directory

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const auth_onboardingController = require('../controllers/auth_onboarding');
const greetmeController = require('../controllers/greetme');

router.get('/greetme', greetmeController.getGreetMe);
router.post('/onboarding', auth_onboardingController.onboarding);
router.post('/signin', auth_onboardingController.signin);
```

There was no compilation error and I called my endpoint on the browser as follows :

| Path | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `myserverip`:`myport`/greetme | --> worked |
| `myserverip`:`myport`/signin | --> Not Found Error below |
| `myserverip`:`myport`/onboarding | --> Not Found Error below |

There was no compilation after starting my NodeJS app.js file but the browser response could not find the signin and onboarding endpoint.

```
Error: Not found
    at /home/linux-user/nodejs_server/app.js:68:19
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/linux-user/nodejs_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

I will appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: "I called my endpoint on the browser" -- Since it's not obvious from your question, I must ask if you are aware that you need a form or some javascript to call a POST endpoint from your browser?   (If you just entered the url, then it'll be a GET-request and since there is none, you'll get a "Error: not found".)

Comment: Did you tried to access POST endpoint with your browser URL searchbar?

Comment: Also your controller is ugly and bloated  up. You should seperate things into services like an bcrypt service file and sql service file

Comment: I called my POST endpoint from ReactJS form and the response was NOT FOUND but when i called GET endpoint from ReactJS I got response. When I called other endpoint with middleware from browser I got "unauthorised" which means they are working because I actually use jwt to protect them but the actual POST endpoints that are to be accessed without jwt check are the ones "not found" but the GET endpoint is found and GET endpoint worked.

Comment: The point is that this APIs are all working on my development localhost machine when I started it but only the GET API is working when the NodeJS is deployed on the Linux VPS server, Post API is giving 404 Not Found error